# PHP and MSSQL Multiple Database Connections

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm having a weird issue with connecting to the master database twice.

```
 $devdb01 = $this->load->database('master',true);
 $dbstate = $this->load->database('mastercheck',true);
```

I have 2 different connection id's but it seems if i'm running a query on the master database it won't execute another query even though its a separate database connection. Basically i'm trying to use a SP that runs a restore database and then run another query checking if the database is still in a restoring state.

I run the queries like the following:

```
$dbresult=$devdb01->query($query);
$dbcheck=$dbstate->query($checkquery);

echo $devdb01->conn_id;
echo $dbstate->conn_id;

$query = "EXECUTE master..sqlbackup '-SQL \"RESTORE DATABASE $dbname FROM DISK = [$restoredir$backupselected] WITH REPLACE, MOVE [$dataname] TO [$datadir$dbname$dataprepend] , MOVE [$logname] TO  [$logdir$dbname$logprepend]\"'";


$dbresult=$devdb01->query($query);
$checkquery="SELECT state_desc from sys.databases where [name]='$dbname'";
$dbcheck=$dbstate->query($checkquery);
var_dump($dbcheck);
```

I just get an output of bool(false) for that var_dump. I verified that the connection id's are different after connecting to the database.

When I try to check the result of the 2nd query I get an error saying i'm calling a member function on a non-object so it must not be executing the query. If I reverse the order it will execute the other query like expected.

I can't tell if this is a PHP limitation? I'm using code igniter so it could be something related to that as well. I tested with SQL Management Studio and it works fine in separate query windows connecting multiple times to the master database. What i'm trying to accomplish is to come up with a way to run this first query then not do anything until I know that query is completed first.

**Update**

It appears if I turn off Persistent Database connections by disabling pconnect it will use the same connection twice.

This is the output from the connection id with pconnect set to false:

Resource id #52Resource id #52

Comment: PHP is capable, like any other language, to connect to N different databases at the same time so thinking that this is PHP limitation first before trying to figure out whether you've done something wrong with the framework in question - is simply wrong. Also, creating an object apparently failed and that's why you're getting that error. Without seeing more code, we can just guess (for example we don't know how you deal with checking the result, and what code produces the error).

Comment: I've been running into this problem for a long time. I've come back to it hoping I can figure it out.